# Google Map with kml file fails when generating signed api

Tags: android-studio, kml

I am trying to create an android App with maps with KmlLayer.
When
i test the project it goes well, but when I try to generate signed apk, then it fails with the below error:

error: cannot find symbol
layer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.MapName, this);
^
symbol:   variable kolkatapujamap
location: class raw

I copied the kml file to the physical path for res/raw.

Can you please let me know whats the solution?
I did the following (different cmbinations of the below with different sequences):

1. Rebuilding the project,
2. Cleaning up the project
3. Restarting Android Studio,
4. Restarting my system
5. Removing the apk files in the build directory
6. Sync Project with Gradle Files
7. Invalidate Caches

Can you please help me?